# Are all carbohydrates a subset of alcohols?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, alcohols, carbohydrates

According to the definition,

> an alcohol is any organic compound in which the hydroxyl functional
>   group (-OH) is bound to a saturated carbon atom.

Monosaccharides such as glucose contain several hydroxyl groups. Does that mean all carbohydrates are a subset of alcohols?

Comment: Yes, it does, why the doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see -OH is bound to a saturated carbon atom in organic chemistry it is Alcohol group.

So answer is **YES**. All carbohydrates are  subset of alcohols.

Though in linear forms they also have aldehyde or ketone group.

[image]

Comment: Roughly speaking, nearly any sufficiently large bioorganic molecule is a member of all classes at once.